# Doctrine2 left join on multiple levels making multiple requests

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, left-join

I have 4 entities that are related in hierarchical levels: `Company`, `Department` and `Employee`. `Company` and `Department` are related with a ManyToOne bidirectional relation. `Department` and `Employee` are related through another entity with 2 OneToMany bidirectional relations because I needed additional parameters for the relation. So basically the final schema is this :

```
Company <-> Department <-> DepartmentEmployee <-> Employee
```

I'm trying to select one department from the company of the current user and to get all the employees of this department. I'm using a custom repository to build my query with the query builder like this:

```
// DepartmentRepository.php

public function getOneWithEmployees($slug, $company)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('d.slug = :slug')
            ->andWhere('c.slug = :company')
            ->setParameters(array('slug' => $slug, 'company' => $company))
        ->leftJoin('d.company', 'c')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->leftJoin('d.departmentEmployee', 'r')
        ->addSelect('r')
        ->leftJoin('r.employee', 'e')
        ->addSelect('e');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

The point being to reduce the number of queries made, but when I execute this query, I still get 32 queries made to the database (I have 15 employees in the department).

When I remove the part

```
->leftJoin('r.employee', 'e')
->addSelect('e')
```

I get only one query executed like expected.

How can I do a left join on a left join without triggering multiples queries?

Comment: Can you try with `$qb->getQuery()->getResult();` instead of `$qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();`? Your request may select only one employee, and require more requests for the other employees.

Comment: No, it's the same result. But I think I found why all these extra queries were made. I'll explain it bellow.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought `getOneOrNullResult()` would fetch only one `Employee` but it must fetch only one `Department` (and its employees), which is correct.

Comment: Exactly. Both methods return one `Department`, except that with `getResult()` it's encapsulated in an array.

Answer (score 9):

My `Employee` entity is the inverse side of 2 OneToOne relations: `User` and `Invitation`. When I explicitly include these relations in the query with `left join`, no extra queries are made, but if I leave them out then Doctrine automatically makes queries to fetch them. Looking in the Doctrine FAQ I found this:

> ### 4.7.1. Why is an extra SQL query executed every time I fetch an entity with a one-to-one relation?
>
> If Doctrine detects that you are fetching an inverse side one-to-one association it has to execute an additional query to load this object, because it cannot know if there is no such object (setting null) or if it should set a proxy and which id this proxy has.
>
> To solve this problem currently a query has to be executed to find out this information.

[Link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#why-is-an-extra-sql-query-executed-every-time-i-fetch-an-entity-with-a-one-to-one-relation)

So the only solution to avoid extra queries is to build my query like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->where('d.slug = :slug')
        ->andWhere('c.slug = :company')
        ->setParameters(array('slug' => $slug, 'company' => $company))
    ->leftJoin('d.company', 'c')
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->leftJoin('d.departmentEmployee', 'r')
    ->addSelect('r')
    ->leftJoin('r.employee', 'e')
    ->addSelect('e')
    ->leftJoin('e.user', 'u')
    ->addSelect('u')
    ->leftJoin('e.invitation', 'i')
    ->addSelect('i');

return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: What is the difference with the question? You added `user` and `invitation`?

Comment: Yes. Doctrine automatically makes a query to get the owning side of the `OneToOne` relations. So to avoid the extra queries, the relations must be included in the query with a left join.